# Android crashes when createBitmap is called X or Y coordinate is > 0

Tags: android, bitmap, move, touch-event

I have written some code to move a bitmap on a touch event. Unfortunately the code crashes when createBitmapis called and either xval or yval is anything other than 0. Here is the code related to this problem. Any assistance would be appreciated:

```
public class AndroidBitmap  extends Activity {

private int yval=0;
private int xval=0;
Bitmap bitmapOrg;
private int bmpWidth;
private int bmpHeight;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_main);
    myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android);

    bmpWidth = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
    bmpHeight = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

    drawMatrix();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            // finger touches the screen
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // finger moves on the screen
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
            // finger leaves the screen
            xval = (int) event.getX();
            yval = (int) event.getY();
            drawMatrix();
            break;
    }
    // tell the system that we handled the event and no further processing is required
    return true; 
} 

private void drawMatrix(){

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, xval, yval,
            bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);      
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

xval or yval is anything other than 0. yes it is true. It must be greater than 0 otherwise it gives error of IllegalArgumentException if the width or height are <= 0. In your code when first time you call drawMatrix(); method then xval and yval pass 0. so it gives error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is just the opposite. The code works fine when the value of xval or yval is 0. It crashes if they are greater.